# How do I generate the max score from this list gathered from another list?

Tags: python

```
def course_grade(coursework_mark,prelim_mark):  

    grade_percentage= int(((coursework_mark + prelim_mark) * 100)/150)

    if grade_percentage<45:                  
        grade="no grade"
    elif grade_percentage<=49:
        grade="D"
    elif grade_percentage<=59:
        grade="C"
    elif grade_percentage<=69:
        grade="B"
    elif grade_percentage>=70:
        grade="A"
    return grade, grade_percentage              

class Student:
    name=""
    coursework_mark = 0
    prelim_mark = 0
    grade_perc = 0
    
student_list=[]
grade_percentage_list= []
tempFile = open("grades.txt","r")

for line in tempFile:
    stripped_line = line.strip() 
    line_elements = stripped_line.split() 

    name = line_elements[0]
    coursework_mark = int(line_elements[1])
    prelim_mark = int(line_elements[2])

    newstudent = Student() 
    newstudent.name = name
    newstudent.coursework_mark = coursework_mark
    newstudent.prelim_mark = prelim_mark
    
    student_list.append(newstudent)

for x in student_list:
    grade, grade_percentage = course_grade(x.coursework_mark, x.prelim_mark) 
    print(x.name, "achieved coursework mark:",x.coursework_mark, "and prelim mark:", x.prelim_mark, "achieving a grade percentage of", grade_percentage, "and a grade", grade )
    
    grade_percentage_list.append(x.name)
    grade_percentage_list.append(grade_percentage)

for x in grade_percentage_list:
    print(x)
```

external text file:

```
Kevin 59 75
Anna 33 80
Paul 55 88
John 10 45
Anne 47 78
Frank 60 90
Susan 57 82
Mary 45 65
James 20 40
Katie 39 59
Mark 55 75
Stacey 25 50
Michael 23 48
Abdul 30 60
Kirsty 54 86
```

Basically, I'm looking to take the names and grade_percentage data from the grade_percentage_list and find out which student has the max score.

I'm looking to only use the tools I have in the block at this level, as I've been told I would be able to do it... but after a hour of tinkering with it, I just can't find out how.

I'm using a for loop to try to iterate through the list, and replace the Max Score with the Current Score if the current score is greater than the max score, but I think the names of the student is interfering with this!!

I've seen a possible solution, which is as follows:

```
maxScore = grade_percentage_list[1]
for currentScore in grade_percentage_list[2:]:
    if(currentScore > maxScore):
        maxScore = currentScore
```

But I can't seem to get this to work. Do I need to create another static class for the grade_percentage?

Answer (score 0):

Having reread your post, this seems to be more in line with what you want.

```
maxname = student_list[0].name
_,maxscore = course_grade(x.coursework_mark, x.prelim_mark)[1]

for x in student_list[1:]:
    _, grade_percentage = course_grade(x.coursework_mark, x.prelim_mark) 
    if grade_percentage > maxscore:
        maxscore = grade_percentage
        maxname = name
```

`maxscore` is the highest grade attained, and `maxname` is the name of the first student on the list who attains this score.

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way to do it with the for loop method I have in the post?: maxScore = grade_percentage_list[1]
for currentScore in grade_percentage_list[2:]:
    if(currentScore > maxScore):
        maxScore = currentScore

Comment: @Vincent Your grade percentage list is inconvenient to use because you include names and scores in the same list

Comment: @VincentOfTheHighlands It would be helpful if you made separate lists of names and grades or changed the construction of the list to `grade_percentage_list.append([name, grade_percentage])`

Answer (score 0):

You could put the names and grade percentage scores into a dictionary, like

```
student_scores = {name: grade_percentage}
```

Then you could `print(max(student_scores, key=student_scores.get))`

Further, your code could be cleaned up a bit by using a CSV or TSV file and reading into a dictionary via `csv.DictReader` ([ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)) (your grades.txt file uses space-separated values, so it's close).

Do you need to create another class? No. Further, why use classes at all? Doing away with them and using dictionaries instead would probably make your code cleaner and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If performance was not a critical aspect of the problem, I would simply sort the list to get the top grade.

```py
for x in student_list:
    grade, grade_percentage = course_grade(x.coursework_mark, x.prelim_mark) 
    print(f"{x.name} achieved coursework mark: {x.coursework_mark} and prelim mark: {x.prelim_mark} achieving a grade percentage of {grade_percentage} and a grade {grade}")

    ## add tuples to our list so we save name and grade together
    grade_percentage_list.append((grade_percentage, x.name))

## --------------
## sort the list as that will give us easy access to the top grade
## --------------
grade_percentage_list.sort(reverse=True)
top_grade = grade_percentage_list[0]
## --------------

print(f"The top grade of {top_grade[0]} was earned by {top_grade[1]}")
```

Note, there are a bunch of cool things you can do with your class in the future to make some of this stuff cleaner.